# Animate curve's bevel factor (preserve the order)

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]
My object contains some separate curves and when I am trying to animate bevel factor, they act simultaneously. But I want them to respect vertices' order (X axis from left to right). 
Can it be done without actual curve separting? Maybe there is a tool like *"Sort elements"* for meshes, but for curves?

Comment: Have you tried using a *Taper Object*? Though I'm not sure how it would behave with multiple segment, I think it would just map it as a whole, i can't test right now

Comment: Without making individual objects I don't think you can control them individually.